# Reading the last n lines of a file

Tags: c#

So like the title of this post says how can i read the last n lines of a file and store them in a List?

Keep it in mind that:

- the file is big (somewhere between 5 MB and 10 MB)
- the file may or may not be locked by another thread
- it is accessed by another thread (a new line is added to file when process finished)

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]

Comment: This isn't a "write it for me" forum. You write some code, we help you fixing it, or you have a simple question, we respond to the question

Comment: It seems to be you want to write a "tail" program. Try googling for tail c# file

Comment: Check out memory mapped files also. Good luck

Comment: You may want to think about synchronization between the the threads. Otherwise the reader may conceivably see an incomplete last line and will in general stop reading at unpredictable spots (which may or may not be a problem).

Comment: I marked the question as duplicate. use Jon's `ReverseLineReader` and use `Take(n)` to take last n lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code:

```
            List<string> Temp = new List<string>();
            int SkipLinesNum = 8;
            var GetAllFileToVar = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Sahbak\LinesToList.txt").Skip(SkipLinesNum);
            for (int n = 0; n < GetAllFileToVar.Count(); n++)
            {
                Temp.Add(GetAllFileToVar.ElementAt(0));
            }
```

now you have List of string called "Temp" that contains all lines from n=8.
you can edit you "n" number any time, and also get it from the user.

this is the most efficient method, where you do not load all file to memory.

Comment: The OP said file sizes would be 5 to 10 MB. Doesnt seem very efficient to load all that stuff into memory...

Comment: @Udontknow Doesn't look too inefficient either, even not on your phone ;-).

Comment: Well, at least it´s working, but i would rather have my programs not wasting resources. If each and every program would work like that, your phone would not be fun to use... ;-)

Comment: This works if you know how many rows you need to skip. But the file is in continuously change so... thanks.

Comment: you can change the "n" number anytime.